# passport-facebook - 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

Tags: html, node.js, facebook, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm trying to develop a facebook connect with node and passport. But I'm having this error in my browser console:

Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%…te_event%2Cuser_birthday%2Cemail&client_id=632348833449996&type=web_server' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'. about:blank:1

This is part of the code:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: "XXX",
    clientSecret: "XXX",
    callbackURL: "`http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback`"
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  var fullname = profile._json.first_name + ' ' + profile._json.last_name;
  // Web services all for user persistence
  }
));

// configure Express
app.configure(function() {
app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));

// Initialize Passport!  Also use passport.session() middleware, to support
// persistent login sessions (recommended).
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
});


app.all('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['read_stream',     'publish_actions','user_interests','read_friendlists','create_event','user_birthday','email'    ]}));

app.all('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook',{ successRedirect:   '/',failureRedirect: '/login' }));

app.listen(3000);
```

On my facebook app configuration I've set the App On Facebook configuration with the following URL: `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're not outputting an X-Frame header on your local server?

Comment: I'm using node just as it comes out of the box. Don really know if there's some place to configure that. I tried to change that header, but without any luck.

Comment: Passport if the one that is setting headers, I'm not doing nothing from my code.

Comment: If you hit the callbackURL directly from a local web browser and view the response headers (via Firebug, or the Chrome developer "Network" tab) is the X-Frame-Options header definitely present? (Best to check.)

Comment: If I hit the URL directly It works, but the x-frame-options:DENY is still there.